# Webpack Autoreload for Unimported Files

Tags: go, webpack, webassembly

I am working with WebAssmbly and Webpack together. My source wasm language is Go. How it works is that there is a webpack load rule that builds and imports the file to my project:

```
// index.js
import wasm from './main.go'
...

// webpack.config.js

...
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.go/,
    use: ["golang-wasm-async-loader2"],
  },
]
...
```

With watch mode enable, this works absolutely wonderfully for my `main.go` file. The issue arises when I change any other file. `Go` compiles all the files in a particular module to a single binary, so I only need to import the main file, and importing other files would just cause it to run multiple times (which I also don't want).

I was wondering if it was possible to force webpack to reload regardless of a file being imported or not?

I looked over [at their watch docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) however I did not find anything :(.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it sees seems that this is impossible to fix from webpack's user api. The only way to fix this is to change how the loader works.

Using [The loader API](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#thisaddcontextdependency), it is possible to add a context dependency or a generic dependency so that those files are watched for reloads as well :)